# Why does Angular 2 binding not work in this case? (sub component input field)

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have an (Angular 2) root component called AppComponent that uses another component called Subcomp. App passes an `@Input()` parameter to Sub. Sub uses this variable for one-way binding in an input field.

Now I...

1. Set the parameter's value to some initial value ("start"); this is displayed in the input field as expected.
2. Change the text in the input field to something else.
3. Click on a button to programmatically reset the value in the AppComponent back to "start".

I then expect the input field to also reset to "start", but instead it keeps displaying the changed text from step 2. Is that correct behavior?

The code:

```
class Todo {
    constructor(public title: string) {}
}

@Component({
    selector: 'subcomp',
    directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES],
    template: `New Title: <input type="text" [ngModel]="subtodo.title">`
})
export class Subcomp {
    @Input() subtodo: Todo;
}

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    directives: [Subcomp],
    template: `To do: {{todo.title}}<br/>
               <subcomp [subtodo]="todo"></subcomp><br/>
               <button (click)="update()">Update</button>`
})
export class AppComponent {

    todo: Todo = new Todo('start');

    update() {
        this.todo = new Todo('start');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is correct behavior.

Because you are only using one-way databinding in `Subcomp`, the value of `todo.title` does not change when you change text in the input field.

When `update()` is called, a new `Todo` object is created, but the value of `todo.title` is `start`, so when Angular change detection looks at `[ngModel]="subtodo.title"`, it sees no change – the old value of `subtodo.title` is `start` as is the current value.  Angular change detection compares primitive types (number, string, boolean) by value.

To prove it, try this:

```
update() {
    this.todo = new Todo('start' + new Date());
}
```

or try this:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="subtodo.title">
```

Comment: OK, this makes sense even if it seems counter-intuitive when using it. Thanks!

Comment: When the `new Todo('xxx')` created by `update()` has a different value it still doesn't update the input. Also not when instead `Todo` `ngModel` is bound to a simple string field. To me it still looks like a bug.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/B9GyaIeqV4TSIJMUR3Qv?p=preview) shows that `new Todo('start' + new Date())` does update the input.  (Using Beta.0, if that matters.  I haven't moved off that yet, as it seems to have fewer bugs.)

Comment: Right, you mentioned it already in your answer. Thanks for the Plunker. Seems I made a mistake when I tried. Now it also works in Dart this way.